# How to delete all textarea in form?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I tried this method:

```
private void ClearTextBoxes()
        {
            Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

            func = (controls) =>
            {
                foreach (Control control in controls)
                    if (control is TextBox)
                        (control as TextBox).Dispose();
                    else
                        func(control.Controls);
            };

            func(Controls);
        }
```

It is does not work, if I even refresh form.

Comment: are you trying to set the `Text` property of each control to "blank"?

Comment: Who say that dispose method delete something?

Comment: Detele its content `control.Text = String.Empty` remove it `container.Controls.Remove(control)`

Comment: There are multiple flavors of "does not work" in this code.  When you Dispose() the textbox then it *also* gets removed from the Controls collection.  That screws up the foreach loop, in effect you'll only get rid of every other textbox.  You have to use a for(;;) loop that iterates backwards.  It might also "not work" because the boxes are on a panel, you have to recurse into the child controls of the form.  And it might "not work" because you meant to not dispose the boxes but to set their Text property to "".  Never force anybody to guess what "does not work" means, there is no point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want delete all textarea from form you should remove it from the parent Controls collection and then always call Dispose on objects that implement IDisposable when you have finished with them, so that any unmanaged resources they own are immediately released. If you will not call Dispose() on not needed textbox it will be cleaned when GC decides and that could happen in the middle of your application run or just in the end. The difference here is that if you call Dispose() explicitly the object finalization will be performed on next run of GC otherwise in first run GC will put the object to finalization queue and clean memory on another run.

```
 private void ClearTextBoxes()
{
    Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

    func = (controls) =>
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                Controls.Remove(control);
            }
            else
             func(control.Controls);

         //Here after removing controls you should call Dispose to clean-up
    };
    func(Controls);
}
```

If you want to celar all your textboxes area than you should call Clear method.

```
private void ClearTextBoxes()
        {
            Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;

            func = (controls) =>
            {
                foreach (Control control in controls)
                    if (control is TextBox)
                        (control as TextBox).Clear();
                    else
                        func(control.Controls);
            };

            func(Controls);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to clear all the text in the `TextBox` Then you should use the `TextBox.Clear()` instance method.

```
public void ClearTextBoxes()
{
    ClearTextBoxes(Controls);
}

private void ClearTextBoxes(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    if(controls == null) 
        return;
    foreach(var control in controls)
    {
        (control as TextBox)?.Clear();
        ClearTextBoxes(control?.Controls);
    }
}
```

If you are trying to remove all the `TextBox` objects from the form, you should use the `ControlCollection.Remove(Control)` instance method or `ControlCollection.RemoveAt(int)` instance method.

```
public void RemoveTextBoxes()
{
    RemoveTextBoxes(Controls);
}

private void RemoveTextBoxes(Control.ControlCollection controls)
{
    if(controls == null) 
        return;
    for(int i = 0; i < controls.Count; ++i)
    {
        var control = controls[i];
        if(control is TextBox)
        {
            controls.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        else 
            RemoveTextBoxes(control?.Controls);
    }
}
```

Note that in this case we can't use a `foreach` loop because we are altering the underlying collection.

Also if you are using C#7 you can have the private method as a local function.

---

**Edit**: As noted by @KrzysztofLa, since `TextBox` implements `IDisposable`, you should call Dispose on it after you've removed it from the collection, assuming you are done working with that specific `TextBox`(you probably are).

Comment: Calling Dispose in loop will break the loop. It is caused because Dispose is almost immediately running GC to remove unmanaged resources.